# Should i turn off MySQL strict mode?

Tags: mysql

I can find lots of articles as to how to turn of MySQL Strict mode, but can not find any advice as to IF this should be turned off.

I have recently installed some code/software that has set all database columns to NOT NULL yet specified no default value and the MySQL inserts are not inserting to every column.
This is of course causing MySQL to throw errors.

The advice from the software support is to disable the MySQL strict mode.
Now i would think the best thing to do is write code that does not cause errors in the first place. I have written code for this server many times, and have never had this issue...

Is turning off MySQL strict mode the best thing to do, and should it be turned off anyhow?

Comment: Of course not. If your columns are defined as NOT NULL, then failing to assign a value *should* raise an error. If NULL is allowed, then remove the NOT NULL constraint. Disabling the database functionality that alerts you to poor practices in your code is never a good idea. Do things properly instead. If you have third-party software that causes these issues, and their advice is to turn off strict mode to fix it, my advice would be to find a different software vendor.

Comment: Thank you Ken. this is what i thought, but was not sure enough before i re-contact the third-party